# How to send this http request in python?

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

I want to make this request in python, via python requests:

```
curl -X POST \
  --form fileItems[0].fileToUpload=@"/path/to/file.mp4"  \
  --form fileItems[0].path="/something/"    \
  --form fileItems[0].replacing=false  \
  --form fileItems[1].fileToUpload=@"/path/to/file.mp4"  \
  --form fileItems[1].path="/something/"    \
  --form fileItems[1].replacing=false  \
someurl.com/files/
```

what would be the equivalent in python?
I wrote this :

```
files = {'fileItems[0].fileToUpload': open('/path/to/file.mp4', 'rb'),
     'fileItems[0].path': '/medias/videos/comedian_contest/', 'fileItems[0].replacing': False}
response = requests.post(url='http://storage.backtory.com/files', files=files, headers=headers)
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 107, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 454, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 388, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 296, in prepare
self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 447, in prepare_body
(body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 150, in _encode_files
fdata = fp.read()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for requests.post.

Comment: @YSelf I have , but I don't know how to implement --form in requests. I am using an API, and that curl function is the only thing that is in the api's documentation , and I have no idea how to pass those arguments to requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. As it turns out, --form sends files in requests.files and other parameters in post parameters. so the equivalent of the above curl function would be :

```
headers = {'Authorization': auth_header, 'some_header': header }
files = {"fileItems[0].fileToUpload": open(file_path, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url='http://some_url.com/some_path', files=files, headers=headers,
                         data={'fileItems[0].path': ["/some_path/path/path/"],
                               'fileItems[0].replacing': [False], })
```

I created a web server for test and performed the curl request on it and figured out what the format of the request should be.

I'm leaving this answer here, in case anyone has the same problem in the future.

Answer (score -2):

First import request module for the python to do the HTTP request and beautifulsoup for parse the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Cralwer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.agent = requests

    def get_page(self,link):
            page = self.agent.get(link).content
            self.page_processor(page)
            break

    def page_processor(self,content):
        print content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
        for jobs in soup.find_all(attrs={"whatever the attribute"}):
                   //DO WHAT EVER YOU WHAT TO DO

get_page(link)
```

It will call the **get_page** with a url and it will go to the link and content goes to the **page_processor**. page processor will parse the content with beautifulSoup.

We can use both methods GET and POST 
For Example 
GET:

```
page = self.agent.get(link).content
```

POST:

```
post_params = {'roll': '1','address':'mumbai'}   
page = self.agent.post(link, files=post_params)
```

Comment: I need to do a POST request . not GET !

Comment: Just do POST with parameter intsted of GET.

Comment: I did , and it just didn't work out . I have even written it in the question